# Extension to link official documentation

Tags: support, search, stack-exchange

Is there any Firefox or Chrome extension that will link manual pages to Stack Overflow?

For e.g. when I visit this page, I will like to see the Stack Overflow posts on the right side of the browser those link to that URL.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html

---

I am asking for this because this query does not return any results:

```sql
select Id from Posts
  where Body like '%https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html%'
```

Comment: that query is extremely expensive. It could work if you limit it to only the python tagged questions.  On site you can query with [url](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fcollections.abc.html) and in the API for questions with an url: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fcollections.abc.html&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true but no one made a plug-in yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion made in the comment, here is a bookmarklet that will search the current page on stack overflow.

```
javascript:{window.location='https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A'+encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0])}
```

I hope someone finds this useful.